# Kick off SharePoint Designer Workflow when certain field has been modified

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

We are trying to kick off a workflow whenever the IT Lead column is modified in our list. This should result in an email notification being sent to the new IT Lead. I have built out the following workflow but the problem is that it sends the "New IT Lead" email when any of the list columns are modified. We'd really prefer to keep this OOTB or using a designer workflow.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Here's the current workflow: http://jessicaberrick.com/sp-screenshot.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on create and on change.

[image]

Comment: Done! Sorry to have missed that.